# Does the 7809 need an input bypass capacitor if it has large output capacitors in parallel?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, bypass-capacitor

I am using RFID [aliexpresslink](https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/4000042532749.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.86c72b219phzBT&algo_pvid=c5c2a3a8-049f-4e3d-ac79-1eadb29c631c&algo_exp_id=c5c2a3a8-049f-4e3d-ac79-1eadb29c631c-22). RFID is suggesting this schematic:
[image]

The 7809 has this schematic in the data sheet:
[image]

1. Why is RFID power design suggesting big capacitors with low resistors? Does it mean that if big capacitors are connected parallel, they don't need input capacitor?
2. Why do they not add an input capacitor?
3. Will this design work without problems? (1000uF capacitor design.) I didn't see anything like this schematic on the internet.
4. If I use only input and output capacitor, will it affect the reading distance? I mean, i I use only 0.33 uF and 0.1 uF, will my read distance be lower?
5. I read in this forum that the 7809's output capacitor is 0.1 uF because in 1970, capacitors were really expensive. What is the best output and input values in these days? (I searched but only I found this schematic 0.33uF and 0.1uF.)

Current schematic of mine.
[image]

For  freewheeling diode:

[image]

Comment: About question 1: it seems they want a really smooth DC. Those three RC are 3 strong lowpass filters.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica thank you.

Comment: I wonder about the competence of an engineer in the 2020s that recommends a 78xx series linear regulator for RF cleanliness purposes. And anyone that calls something like this "as pure as battery"... Not saying the module is badly designed, just that the person responsible for the aliexpress offer was just going around copying decades obsolete schematics from the internet without really understanding them. I have serious doubts this works well – a 1000µF capacitor very likely has a non-negligible internal series resistance, which means that while RF from the power supply might be

Comment: well-suppressed, now the voltage regulation becomes bad, which might even be worse.

Comment: Say, your 1000µF has a dissipation factor of 0.16 (pretty typical), so at 134 kHz (which will definitely appear as modulation in the current drawn by the amplifier) this capacitor exhibits 21 Ω resistance; so that the HF has to be fed from the 3Ω between the 7809 and VCC_RF (capacitors mostly useless) . This basically negates any voltage regulation. In other words: Either the board itself has a linear regulator that would take care of all relevant frequencies by itself, so the external filtering is useless, or it doesn't, in which case this thing becomes a nonlinearly oscillating RF nightmare.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for your comments. Can you suggest me that current linear regulators used for RFs ?

Comment: yeah, go to a proper electronics distributor (Farnell, digikey, mouser, …), and look for things that don't start with LM, have the right in- and output voltages, and then check the noise rejection properties at frequencies that are relevant. **You need to first figure out what these would be**, I'm not even convinced there's an actual need for a linear regulator with a modern switch-mode supply. As said, in all likelihood that board has its own regulator with its own noise rejection and the people putting together the aliexpress website were just stealing random schematics from forums.

Comment: Okay, thank you again. "all likelihood that board has its own regulator" I tried with power supplies 9V (I didn't use capacitor or something only 9V's + and -). It was working 4-5 cm below the maximum range.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What's the calculation that results in the 21 Ohms? If it's DF = ESR/Xc, then I don't see where the 21 Ohms comes from.

Comment: @DKNguyen *should* be \$\lvert j\omega C\rvert \cdot \text{DF}=2\pi \cdot 134\,\Omega\cdot0.16\$, I think. But then I wouldn't arrive at the same 21 Ω; hm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Even in that case I don't see where the calculation follows from unless you are treating \$X_c = j\omega C\$ for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most regulators will get unstable if the impedance of the input power supply is too inductive, due to long wires or traces. So an input capacitor is added.

You can use whatever value of cap you already have that's equal or greater to what the manufacturer says in the datasheet. If the input supply bulk caps are close, then it's probably not necessary, but a 1µF SMD caps only costs a few cents...

> Why is RFID power design suggesting big capacitors with low resistors?

Probably because their board has low power supply rejection and needs clean power. To be honest, it looks a bit overkill.

Personally I'd use a snubber on the transformer to remove rectifier noise at the source, and a large 1000µF output cap because RFID draws pulsed current.

Comment: Thank you. If you use 1000 µF output capacitor,  will you use 0.33 uF input capacitor. I read Justme's explanation but I just wanted the ask again.

Comment: You need an input cap (0.33µF or whatever value, use what you got) if there is not already an input cap, for example after the rectifier if you use a transformer+rectifier+caps supply.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome 100 nF or 330 nF are advisable because they work better on high frequencies, where large (electrolytic) don't. It is always better, to put a small cap near the regulator.

Comment: Okay, thank you again. I will use 330 nF then. I will keep in mind "It is always better, to put a small cap near the regulator."

Comment: Personally I put 1µF MLCC because I bought a large quantity to get the discount lol. 78xx was designed back in the day before multilayer boards and cheap low ESR caps so it is absolutely not picky about caps. There is no difference in frequency response between thru hole ceramics and electrolytics  of the same pin spacing. SMD ceramics are much better at HF of course.

Comment: Okay simply I need to select between 100 and 1µF for input (or more but I will stick with these values.). I will use smd capacitor for input probably but output capacitor will be electrolytic capacitor and it will be 10x15 or bigger. This won't be a problem right?

Comment: I think you worry too much ;) Will you be using transformer+diodes, or a switching power supply? If so, onboard or connected by cable and usual barrel connector?

Comment: @bobflux yes, I worry to much, I will get used to it (I hope). I will use 24 V to 12V switching regulator. I will connect 12V with PCB line to 9V. I have one more question is this 1ohm resistor okay? Isn't it too low for 4 capacitor.

Comment: Hmmm... if you use DC-DC switcher and its frequency is close to your RFID frequency, then you could get interference. Got a link on the DC-DC?

Comment: I am using R-78E12-0.5 [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/468/R_78E_0_5-1711129.pdf)

Comment: Ah ok that runs at 570kHz, far above your RFID frequency, so it should be OK. If you run into trouble, I guess you'll need a filter, but you'll only know when it's powered up. If you haven't ordered your components yet, where are you buying?

Comment: [ozdisan.com](https://www.ozdisan.com/) I am gonna buy from here.

Comment: OK you can get 2 of these just in case, as cheap insurance https://www.ozdisan.com/passive-components/inductors/ferrite-beads/R6H6X10-3TS

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me a lot. Last question where should I put this ferrite beads? Should I place before the input capacitor or after the output ?

Comment: They replace 1R resistors between your big output caps. They have much higher impedance at HF, so much better filtering.

Comment: Thank you so much, have a nice day.

Comment: @bobflux I tried the circuit , really don't need 3 caps. I added schematic of breadboard. I am using electrolyte capacitors. I used 24V because I don't have R-7812 for now. Would you still use 1R resistor on this schematic or should I just  remove it ?

Comment: I have a hunch they went overkill on the caps to get less customers bothering them about noise issues lol. No need for 1R resistor with 7812. The purpose of the resistor is to make a CRC filter (but a CLC filter with the ferrite is better), but if you have only one cap, there's no CRC filter, so the resistor is just for decoration.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the presence of an input bypass capacitor does not depend on how much capacitance there is on the output. It depends on many other factors, such as for example how long wires there are to the input  bulk capacitor. If 1 cm, most likely a separate bypass is not needed, if 1 meter, most likely a separate bypass is needed.

Bear in mind that we don't know why the circuit is like that, ask the one who provided the circuit. Internet is full of circuits that look random and made by hobbyists and tinkerers instead of engineers.

1. The regulator may omit the drawing of the input bypass capacitor, if it is expected to be near a power supply bulk capacitance which is not drawn in the circuit. In general, it is best to have the 330nF input capacitor that to omit it. The fact that there is a lot of output bulk capacitance does not mean you can omit the input bypass cap. Take the circuit as a block diagram type of example circuit, not as exact design.
2. They may assume or expect that the power supply with its bulk capacitors is within short distance from the regulator input, and it is just an example picture, because it might be different depending on which regulator you use. It may not resemble the exact way how you should do things.
3. It might work. Or it might have problems. It is impossible to say just by looking this circuit in isolation. If you have a random 12V power supply, there is no way to prove it works with it or it won't. And there must be better ways to do it than with three high value caps. The first problem might be that the inrush current is so large that a power supply might hit a current limit and shut down or blows a fuse on the supply output. So it may require a power supply with large output current, even if the circuit consumption is very small.
4. How would we know how it affects it. If you remove bulk caps and add input bypass, it might even work better depending on your power supply which is unknown. The point is, if there is no specs what the RF device needs from the power supply and regulator, it is impossible to know what power supply and regulator is good enough for the RF device.
5. No the values are not 330nF and 100nF because capacitors were expensive. The manufacturer just guarantees that these values of high frequency bypass caps have proper impedance range to keep the regulator stable. The user of the regulator is responsible for using larger bulk capacitors on input and output if necessary depending on the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for huge explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check that 78xx schematic. To the best of my knowledge, pin 2 is GND and pin 3 is OUT. I stumbled upon this looking up the pinout on google and it might confuse some folks, causing premature release of The Magic Smoke.
If you want a relatively stable and quiet power supply with one of these, simply throw lots of capapcitance at it, say a 470uF plus a 100nF in parallel on the input and a 1000uF plus 100nF in parallel on the output. The more the better, depending on the current draw of the application and surge-load capability of the supply. For good measure use ferrite chokes on the in and out, a donut type coil one on input and a rf blocking barrel on the output. Any rf pickup by the circuit or its wires will make it into your device, consider using a clip-on ferrite close to the device on the supply wire. That will kill any remaining junk right at the device side.

Comment: Be careful with inductivities on the input. Depending on the situation they might form an oscillator together with the input capacitance or lead to really high transient voltages when current consumption after the 7809 changes. I've made that error once and killed some electronics before realizing my mistake... A freewheeling diode solved the issue.

Comment: Which pin is which depends on how you number them. The datasheet from where this numbering is copied from uses number 3 for the middle pin, which means, middle pin is still ground regardless of the pin numbering scheme.

Comment: Kruemi, The typical input rf chokes are only a few turns of thick wire on a donut shaped core, they block rf but are very low inductance. I use whatever I can scavenge from old equipment, any ol' ferrite core will do, snip off the original wire and make a few loops of your input wire through it. 
Justme:
Have a look at any datasheet for the 78xx series regulators, They are always 1-In, 2-Gnd, 3-Out. The datasheet you are referring to is a very odd one, where does it come from? To avoid  mishaps there would have to be a drawing that shows the odd numbering clearly.

Comment: Thank you DoctorZ for your comment. @kruemi I also want to thank you for your comment. I added photo for freewheeling diode on question. Is that what you say ? I can add diode like this.

Comment: @DoctorZ I've meade the mistake of just putting in the same Component i've used elsewhere on the board. Which was from the switching regulators. I've killed two 7805 until I realized my mistake. Sadly, the 7805 failed short which put 24V instead of 5V on the components. Luckily, I had not place the expensive ADC and analog switches. Also I had not placed the opamps. But I killed two Arduino (I did not like +24V on Aref) and one I2C Isolator in the process. That's why I put out this warning. Coils can be mean beasts!